# Linking in a custom library with custom stylesheets and graphics

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I have two Qt projects. The first project builds a library that provides a widget for the main window. The second project then uses this library and creates custom widgets to plug into it and define implementation.

Everything works properly except for the graphics not showing up in the second project that includes the library. The widgets show up just fine, but nothing from the stylesheet is displayed.

Is there something else I'm forgetting to do?

For example, I've made this frame...

```
namespace saiwidgets {

class SAIWIDGETSSHARED_EXPORT Frame : public QFrame {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Frame(QFrame* parent  = nullptr);
    Frame(QWidget* widget, QFrame* parent  = nullptr);
    ~Frame();

    void addWidget(QWidget* value);

protected:
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e) override;

    QVBoxLayout layout;
};

}
```

And load the stylesheet like this...

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QFile styleFile( %path to the stylesheet% );
styleFile.open( QFile::ReadOnly );

QString style( styleFile.readAll() );
a.setStyleSheet( style );
```

Implementation omitted...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You haven't shown any code, which is going to make it very hard for anybody to troubleshoot the problem. What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you. Well, I just inherited Qt widgets and placed them into the library... but okay :3 I'll add the example.

Comment: Also I tried to apply the stylesheet manually right in the custom widget, it works, of course...

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Just apply the stylesheet to the parent window.